# C: given known address and type, how to print values stored in it?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

I am doing a homework of C programming.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct JustArray {
    char *x;
  } JustArray;

int main()
{
    JustArray Items[12];
    char *d = "Test";

    Items[0].x = (char *) &d;
    printf("Pointer: %p\n", &d);
    printf("Address: %u\n",&d);
    printf("Value: %s\n", d);
/*------------------------------------*/
//Knowing address of d from above, print value stored in it using Items[0].x. Cannot use &d, *d, or d.
    char *ptr;
    ptr = Items[0].x;
    printf("%p\n", Items[0].x);
    printf("%p\n", &ptr);
    printf("%s\n", ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of ptr needs to be "Test" as well but it is showing me weird characters. The assignment is to have find a way to use the address info in Items[0].x and print its value "Test" in console. I could not find a way to do it...

Comment: Think about how to recreate the value of `d` from `ptr`. (You will need to do the reverse of the process used to set the value of `Items[0].x`)

Comment: Naming variables with capital letters like `Items` is something you'll want to avoid. That reads like a class definition, which clearly this isn't.

Comment: @tadman there are no class definitions in C

Comment: @M.M Exactly why seeing that capital letter is confusing.

Comment: @tadman IMO that indicates a problem with yourself, perhaps you are letting your Java conventions affect your C programming or something

Comment: @M.M The vast majority of C style guides discourage using capital letters for variables. I'm just pointing out how irregular this is, and that it should probably be lower-case. Not everyone writes C code all day, every day.

Comment: Chen Hubert,   To print without specifying a format is the crux of code [Formatted print without the need to specify type matching specifiers using _Generic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115143/formatted-print-without-the-need-to-specify-type-matching-specifiers-using-gene) - likely beyond where you are now.  It does have a technical issue that needs fixing, but to be clear: there are many ways to solves issues in C, especially when code "knows" the pointer type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that the value of a pointer is an address. The content of a pointer (i.e. its dereference, the value pointed, addressed by it) is a value (with the type being pointed) which is in another place. So a *int** has as value an address of another variable (of type *int*) **which is stored in another address**. Note that each primitive variable in C is the name of a data stored in some address.

```
int p = 1;
```

*p* above is a var of type *int*. It has *1* as value, which is directly given by *p* (so *p == 1*). *p* has an address (say 0x11111) that can be accessed with *&p* (so *&p == 0x11111*). Thus, *p* is the name of a variable  whose value is an int (*1*) and whose address is *0x11111* (given by *&p*). This means that the value *1* (which is an int) is stored in the address *0x11111*.

```
int* q = 0x22222;
```

*q* above is a var of type *int** (pointer to *int*, meaning "an address to a var of type *int*"). ***q* has an address as value** (in this case is 0x22222), which is directly given by *q* (so *q == 0x22222*). **but *q* also has an address** (say *0x33333*), which can be accessed with *&q* (so *&q == 0x33333*). Thus, *q* is the name of a variable whose value is an address to *int* (*0x22222*, given by *q*) and whose address is *0x33333* (given by *&q*). Basically, the value *0x22222* (which is an address) is stored in the address *0x33333*.

You can use the prefix operator *** over *q* to dereference it, i.e. access its content, which is the value stored in the address *0x22222*, which is the value of *q*. So basically we have: *q==0x22222*, *&q==0x33333*, and **q==[whatever is the value stored in the adress 0x22222*]. Now consider this:

```
int* r = &p;
```

Remember that *p* has value *1* (an *int* given by *p* itself) and address *0x11111* (given by *&p*). Now I declared a pointer to *int* called *r* and initialized it with the address of *p* (*0x11111*). Thus, *r* is a pointer whose value is an adress (*0x11111*), but it also has an address (say *0x44444*).

The operator *** prefixing a pointer lets us access the value of the address that is its value. So **r* will give us *1* because *1* is the value stored in the address *0x11111*, which is the value of *r* and the address of *p* at the same time. So *r==&p* (*0x11111==0x11111*) and **r==p* (*1==1*).

Now lets go back to your code. When you declare a *char** you already have a pointer, so the printing of it will be an address if you set *%p* as the desired format or a string if you set *%s* as the desired format. (The *%s* makes the function *printf* iterate throughout **the contents** whose start address is the value of the given pointer (and it stops when it reaches a *'\0'*). I fixed your code (and modified it a little bit for the sake of readability). The problem was that you were sending the addresses of the pointers instead of the pointers themselves to the function *printf*.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct justArray
{
    char* x;
}
JustArray;

int main()
{
    //d is a pointer whose content is an address, not a char 'T'
    char* d = "Test";
    printf("Pointer: %p\n", d); //print the address (no need for &)
    printf("Address: %lu\n", (long unsigned) d); //print the address again as long unsigned)
    printf("Value: %s\n", d); //print a string because of the %s

    JustArray Items[12];
    Items[0].x = d;
    printf("%p\n", Items[0].x); //Items[0].x == d, so it prints the same address

    char* ptr = Items[0].x;
    printf("%p\n", ptr); //ptr == Items[0].x, so it prints again the same address
    printf("%s\n", ptr); //prints the string now because of the %s

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program will be:

```
Pointer: 0x400734
Address: 4196148
Value: Test
0x400734
0x400734
Test
```

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to notice what this line does:

```
Items[0].x = (char *) &d;
```

Observe first that `d` is a `char *` (i.e. a null-terminated string in this case), thus `&d` (taking a reference to it) must yield a value of type `char * *` (i.e. a pointer to a pointer to a char, or a pointer to a string). The cast to `char *` has to be done for the C type checker to accept the code. [Note that this is considered very bad practice, since you are forcing a value of one type into a value of another type that makes no sense. It's just an exercise though, and it's precisely this "bad practice" that makes it a bit of a challenge, so let's ignore that for now.]

Now, to get back `d` again, given just `Items[0].x`, we need to sort of "invert" the operations of the above line of code. We must first convert `Items[0].x` to its meaningful type, `char * *`, then dereference the result once to get a value of type `char *` (i.e. a null-terminated string).

```
char *d_again = *((char * *) Items[0].x);
printf("%s\n", d_again);
```

And viola!